# Ext 5.1.1, Extend Ext.window.Toast

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I am attempting to extend `Ext.window.Toast` so that I can reduce the amount of repeated code throughout my application when attempting to toast the user; however, despite reading the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.window.Toast) on toasts and trying a number of different placements of the `callParent()` in the `initComponent()` function, I am unable to "toast" my custom toast.

Here is the custom toast (relatively basic):

```
Ext.define('custom.path.to.ResponseToastWindow', {
    extend : 'Ext.window.Toast',
    xtype  : // xtype...

    requires : [
        'Ext.XTemplate'
    ],

    tpl             : null,

    html            : null,
    // configs... 
    shadowOffset    : 5,

    config : {
        message         : '',
        title           : '',
        someData    : []
    },

    initComponent : function () {
        var me = this;

        me.tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
            // template script
            // 'message' property utilized, here
        );

        me.html = me.tpl.apply(me.someData);
        me.callParent();
    }
});
```

Here is the attempt to toast the custom window:

```
var bob = Ext.create('custom.path.to.ResponseToastWindow', {
        message     : 'objects modified',
        title       : 'Successes',
        someData    : // some data
    });

    Ext.toast(bob);
```

Am I missing anything substantial?

From what I can tell, `Ext.window.Toast` should be extendable. If calling toast with the above config. found on the class (rather than passing in an object), the toast works. Further, all of the configurations are appropriately set on the created object.

Comment: Ext.toast() is specting `Ext.toast(message, title, align, iconCls);` not an object extended from Ext.Window.Toast. Did you try to use `bob.show()`?

Comment: @qmat is right, where did you see that you can call `Ext.toast(toastInstance)`? The doc you say you read does not offer that option.

Comment: @DrakeES it can also take a config. "object", too. I'll post an answer later, today, that still enables the use of `.toast`

Comment: You are now not passing a config object, but a component. If it's true what you are saying only pass the config object what you are using for the component creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where I end up with. Works like a charm:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.define('ResponseToastWindow', {
            extend: 'Ext.window.Toast',
            xtype: 'myToast',

            tpl: '<span>{message}</span><br><span>{data}</span>',
            shadowOffset: 5,
            align: 't',
            width: 200,

            config: {
                message: '',
                title: '',
                someData: []
            },

            initComponent: function() {
                var me = this;

                me.callParent();

                me.setData({
                    message: me.getMessage(),
                    data: me.getSomeData()
                });
            }
        });

        var bob = Ext.create('ResponseToastWindow', {
            message: 'objects modified',
            title: 'Successes',
            someData: 'Some data'
        });

        bob.show();

        bob = Ext.toast({
             html: 'Data Saved',
             title: 'My Title',
             width: 200,
             align: 't'
         });

        bob.show();
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/rrs

Comment: thank you for your response. Given the OP, I have +1`ed and accepted your answer as it directly addresses the problem. If you're interested, you can check out my answer, below, too.

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.window.Toast` is extendable as Tarabass has demonstrated in his question; however, the [source](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/source/Toast.html#Ext-window-Toast) for the call to `Ext.toast` tells us a few important things:

```
function (Toast) {
    Ext.toast = function (message, title, align, iconCls) {
        var config = message,
            toast;

        if (Ext.isString(message)) {
            config = {
                title: title,
                html: message,
                iconCls: iconCls
            };
            if (align) {
                config.align = align;
            }
        }

        toast = new Toast(config);
        toast.show();
        return toast;
    };
});
```

The most important piece of the source code is the call to `Ext.isString(message)`. Here, an evaluation is performed to determine whether or not the three proceeding parameters (title, etc.) should be payed attention to and - if the evaluation results in `true` - "instantiates" a new config. object.

However, it is possible, then, to pass a config. directly to the call to `Ext.toast`.

The way I approached the problem after this revelation was to implement the factory pattern with an Ext singleton.

```
Ext.define('Path.to.custom.package.ToastConfig', {
    alternateClassName : 'ToastConfig',

    requires : [
        'Ext.XTemplate'
    ],

    singleton       : true, // this class is a singleton

    autoScroll      : true,
    // other config. options referenced, below....
    shadowOffset    : 5,

   /**
     * factory
    */
    makeToast : function (title, message, data) {
        var me  = this,
            tpl = null;

        tpl = me.getPromiseToastTemplate(message);


        return {
            html            : tpl.apply(data),
            title           : title,
            autoScroll      : me.autoScroll,
            // other configs...
            shadowOffset    : me.shadowOffset
        };
    },

// ...
```

The result of a call to this singleton's `makeToast()` function can then be passed to the `Ext.toast` function.